# How to get current segment fron m3u8 in Android?

Tags: android, stream, translation, m3u8

I have online translation m3u8. This translation consist of many *.ts files, where every file is 3 seconds video segment. I want to get current played sound from this stream. I try to get sound from one *.ts and I think I can. But how I can get current segment?

Maybe somebody know the ways, how to get sound from online translaition?